# GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this) always returns empty string, even after successful call to register

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing GCM - the first thing I do is call GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId to see if the device is registered.  It's not (empty string is returned), so I make the asynchronous call to GCMRegistrar.register.  As expected, my intent service (derived from GCMBaseIntentService) gets its onRegistered() method called, along with a token that my server can use to send GCM messages to this device.  So far, so good.

However, the next time I run the app, I would expect that first call to GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId to return the token that I got back in my intent service's onRegistered function.  But I get the empty string again.  I thought that the GCM client library (gcm.jar) would save the GCM registration id (token) to a private SharedPreferences object -- in fact, the documentation for the GCMRegistrar class (http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/client-javadoc/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html) states "Note: this class uses a private SharedPreferences object to keep track of the registration token"

I have not unregistered the device, uninstalled the application, or updated the versionCode. Any ideas what I am missing? Thanks

Note -- This question has been posted in google groups under the android-gcm tag. The url is here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/4FPqZLzlvE4

Mark Murphy (a Commons Guy) has been real helpful with initial diagnosis of the problem but nothing concrete has surfaced

**Update Edit - Here is the relevant part of my AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <receiver android:name=".push.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.myapp.package.name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".push.GCMIntentService" />
```

Comment: any success to get device id, I am having same prob..

Comment: oh we have this problem too... Isn't there any solution??

Comment: same problem:  successful registration, but only get empty string with getRegistrationId().  have you found anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I double checked the AndroidManifest to ensure that our service was defined properly and it was. In the end I went with a hack that involved writing to shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

***"category android:name="*write down your full package name*" />"***

give your package in manifest like above.

Comment: I have added my full package name to the mainfest. "com.myapp.package.name" is just a replacement string for the actual package name.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have called `GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);` method somewhere that is called when app is closed. Maybe in `onDestroy()` ??
In our case it was the problem :)

The method actually un-registers the device from Google services, so it does not get a token until you open your app and get the register action called.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the documentation for the sample app. In the manifest it says:

```
      By default, it must be named .GCMIntentService, unless the
      application uses a custom BroadcastReceiver that redefines its name.
```

In your manifest you are using

```
<service android:name=".push.GCMIntentService" />
```

You are not placing this service on the root level and not making a custom BroadcastReceiver. This should be :

```
<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

I was having the same problem, moving the service to the root of my package solved the problem. This is kinda silly solution though.

Answer (score 0):

also add GCM permission into your manifest and verify google gmc key.

App receives GCM messages.

Answer (score 0):

No worries, If getRegistrationId returns empty string, that is because some times it takes time to register to the GCM Cloud. You should wait for onRegistration method to trigger in the GCMIntent Service class.

Once it is registered, you will receive the registrationID, then you can do whatever you want to with it(most likely you would have to send it to your web database, you can call Async from onRegistration callback method).

@Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {

```
    //Log.i("Registration", arg1.toString());  
    // This is where you need to call your server to record the device registration id.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

put your service class which derived from GCMIntent service in the root package of your application. **i mean if your application package is** **com.stackoverflow.android**  ***your service class should reside in this package*** not in one of the others package pakage of your application project. assure to put all required permission in the manifest file

Comment: This answer does not provide any new information which is not already provided by other answers to this question.